# How to convert java primitive float to Kotlin Float?

Tags: java, kotlin, primitive

I am trying to convert primitive `float` from java to `Float` in kotlin like this:

```
kotlinFloat = myJavaObject.floatProperty()
```

But I am getting error that the types are not compatible etc.

I was looking like everywhere to find the answer but I was not able to. I was trying to create Float object -> `Float(myJavaObject.floatProperty())` but it is failling since Float constructor is private.

I am very new to kotlin and I know this sounds stupid but I was trying to find the answer for like 20 minutes and could not find any.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator

Comment: What is the return type of `floatProperty`?

Comment: "types are not compatible etc." — Could you please show the exact error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin has `to___` extension methods for things like this. What you need is `toFloat()`

```
kotlinFloat = myJavaObject.floatProperty().toFloat()
```